# A Differential Equation with Nested Functions

Tags: differential-equations, functional-equations

This was posted to Math Stackexchange, but got no useful answers, and the more I think about it, the harder it seems.

I would like to know whether there exists a differentiable function from the (open or closed) unit interval to itself satisfying
$$1-x-f(f(x))-f(x)f'(f(x))=0$$
for all $x$.

Ideally, I'd also like a list of all such functions.

This arose in the course of an economics problem whose description would be off-topic here, so lest this question seem too localized, let me pose a general question:

> What techniques are available for solving functional equations of the above type?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the MSE question?

Comment: "Unit interval" is $(0,1)$, right?

Comment: can you provide some background?

Comment: @fedja:  Yes, "unit interval" is (0,1).

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix

Comment: @SteveHuntsman:  Thanks.  This idea is new to me.  I'll play with it.

Comment: I hope applied mathematics is not OT.  Maybe if the background is too involved and there is no explanatory paper or website to link to, you could add an appendix at the end of the question for those who might be interested.

Comment: Carl:  I expect to have something written up next week and will edit to add a link when I have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $$1-x=f(f(x))+f(x)f'(f(x)).$$
Note, that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2$ and thus the function is injective on $(0,1).$ Therefore, it is strictly monotone. This implies that $f(f(x))$ is strictly increasing.

If $f$ is increasing, then $f'(f(x))\ge 0$ and thus
$1-x\ge f(f(x)).$ Letting $x\to 1$ leads to a contradiction.

If $f: (0,1)\to [0,1]$ and $f$ decreases, then $f(x)\cdot f'(f(x))\le 0$ and $1-x\le f(f(x)).$ Letting $x\to 0$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: "decreasing" is not the same as "negative". Besides, nobody said that $f$ is onto.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point. It seems I have never used the fact that it is onto. According to OP, the range of $f$ has to be inside $(0,1).$

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier: I just claimed that if $f'(f(x))> 0$ at some point then $f'(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ which would imply that $f(f(x))$ has to be small around $1.$

Comment: @Safoura: the point fedja is making is that you can only obtain $f'(x)f''(f(x))\leq 0$ from the fact that $f'(f(x))$ decreases. Yet I agree with you: I don't see where the «onto» objection is relevant here.

Comment: Right, the onto part of the comment was my mistake (I just missed one trivial logical step in the argument) :-).

Comment: @Safoura: sorry, I may be slow here but would you care to explain your second comment? How do you conclude $f'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, and how does it pertain to the rest of your claim and your proof?

Comment: well the function is either increasing or decreasing and therefore the sign of the derivative is determined by its sign at one point. Now if $f'(x)\ge 0,$ then $1-x\ge f(f(x))$ and $f(f(x))$ increases. This is impossible around 1.

Comment: Yeah, I finally realized that you have a valid argument though the way it is written is quite sloppy (note, for example, that the inequality $f'(y)\ge 0$ for a single $y$ doesn't imply that $f$ is increasing: it can be that $f'(y)=0$ and $f'<0$ everywhere else). I apologize for my being dense...

Comment: Thanks for your precision. Maybe you could modify your answer a bit to remove any ambiguity. Especially for the set of dense people I also belong too ;)

Comment: In other words, unless I'm mistaken : If $f$ is increasing, then $f' \geq 0$, and therefore $1-x \geq f(f(x))$ for all $x$. Letting $x \to 1$ gives a contradiction, since $f \circ f$ is increasing. Hence $f$ must be decreasing, so that $f' \leq 0$, and in this case we get $1-x \leq f(f(x))$ for all $x$, and letting $x \to 0$ gives a contradiction. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I am sorry for being too sketchy. The reason is that I typed more technical solution to the partial case assuming some smoothness and then realized that we do not need anything (apparently I deleted too much). I am editing the answer...

Comment: Safoura:  Thank you.  I'm surprised to learn that this is so easy (though of course it's only easy when you're very clever).  This might or might not make its way into a paper, but in case it does, I'll be glad for an email with guidance on how you'd like to be acknowledged.